# Getting the following error while trying to add the worklight.mpack file in xamarin studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, xamarin-studio

I am trying to use worklight server via xamarin. I added worklight component to my project. After this when I go for addins option in the preferences and open the IBMWorklight_1.1.0.mpack I get following error.

[image]

Comment: What is the version of the Xamarin Component you are using ? Also, please mention the version of Xamarin Studio you're using. 

The Addin provides a way of starting or stopping the MobileFirst server from within Xamarin Studio. These same operations can be achieved using the MobileFirst CLI or MobileFirst Studio.

Comment: xamarin component - ibm mobilefirstsdk (8.0)

Comment: xamarin version6.1.2

Comment: The Addin is not shipped with the version of Xamarin Component you specify. It is only shipped with earlier versions. Can you double check the version and where you obtained the mpack file from ? 

In any case, operations such as starting/stopping the server etc. are best performed using the CLI

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @srik, the add-in is not shipped with the version of Xamarin Component you're using.

It is suggested that you will try with an earlier release.